# how to show the contract form like text in the ipad application

Tags: iphone, html, forms, ipad, textview

I want to make a ipad application in which there will be form in which user will enter name and date and other things will be already hardcode as show in the following form so which control may i use to get this functionality may i use TextView or webView to perform the functioning.

[image]

this is the top of the form which should be in ipad in which user will enter date and doctor name

and below is the form where user will sign in the bottom in the above page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't found a good (non-paid) solution for editing forms and pdf files. Generally you can display the form with a UIWebView then place your UITextFields over top of the editable areas to store the data you need. Either way the fields need mapped out so it's not that tough for the form you have here.

The other solution is to recreate the forms using textFields and native components.

Comment: how may i show scrolling i think i need to use Scroll View and add all the things in that to work perfect